nginx api gateway doesn't transfer POST request body to the microservice
`http {
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/words/ {
        proxy_pass ${WORDS_APP_URL};
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type $content_type;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length $content_length;
    }

    location /api/users/ {
        proxy_pass ${USERS_APP_URL};
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type $content_type;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length $content_length;
    }
}

`
this is code for nginx, it works except transfering request body to my express app, when i'm tring to make a request directly to microservice everything works as expected, so problem is connected with nginx. I'm at nginx, and i tryed everything so code might be a little bit messy
i tryed making a POST request using postman, and req.body is empty
